# How to select photos by file-name when opening from inside an app?

Tags: android-10

I am converting hundreds of A4 pages of handwritten text into computer text with the amazing Pen to Script app on my Android 10 phone. I got many more to process and I go crazy on one detail:

Here is my problem: Every time I start a new page, I have to **select** its photo from a very full folder. But every time I get offered some useless (for this purpose) "app switcher" (I am not sure that is its correct name) where I see recent photos and a choice of several apps to select photos.

Problem is also that at thumbnail-size on a phone, **all pages of handwritten text look the same**.

In my app switcher I found an icon that looks like six tiny white rectangles on a small grey rectangle. This gives me the view I need: file names rather than thumb-nails.

Update: The view which give me the file-names in the app switcher is called "list view"; found that on long-tap on its icon. **So please, how can I set "list view" as my default to come up each time I have to select a photo?**

I would have preferred to have Total Commander come up, whenever I have to select a photo. But if a user can show me how to make the file-name-view sticky in my app switcher, that would be a solution for this present project.

Comment: Usually the way how an image is selected/chosen is defined by the app that requests the image. Also the apps shown in the "app switcher" is pupulated by those apps that define they can provide an image. As TC can only select but not provide an image it is not shown here. As workaround I would try to make one directory per image and move the image in there. If the "Pen to Script App" supports it may be even possible to launch the app from outside alterady defining the photo to be processed. That may be possible via Intent opened via `adb` or on the shell of the app Termux.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, TC is one of the apps that are being offered by the annoying switcher step in my work flow, next to "Bug reports"[sic], "Drive", "Photos", "Photos" and "Recent Images". So I can chose TC but cannot make that choice stick. Your idea about hundreds of folders does not help, but - temporarily - assign Pen to Script to open all photos is promissing, thank you, will test that now. Let you know in a moment.

Comment: So sad, my phone is offering 112 apps which can potentially open a photo when hit in my file explorer, but Pen to Script has not registered itself for that purpose. The idea was great, just what one needs from a forum when goind brain-dead from manually batch-processing stuff.

Comment: By chance I found a semi-solution: when Pen to Script is showing me the unloved app switcher to select the next photo, I can tap on a sad looking grey icon to the right of the heading "recent images". This gives me the files names I need, rather than thumbs. This too I have not found how to make stick, but it saves me several clicks per page, because I no longer need Total Commander.

Comment: Update: The view which give me the file-names in the app switcher is called "list view"; found that on long-tap on its icon. So please, how can I set "list view" as my default to come up each time I have to select a photo?